# cURL and scraping websites that look to detect Frames support

Tags: php, security, curl, screen-scraping, frames

I'm trying to pull information from Natwest's Online Banking service using PHP / cURL - the idea being that if it's actually possible to do, then I could maybe make a more mobile-friendly site to access the service, or maybe an Android app.

The pages obviously employ some security features involving Javascript, framesets and who knows what else. From what I can tell, there's no cookie manipulation going on in the Javascript (that I can see), but there's something going on with the generated URLs in the page source... and whenever I try to view a page that would be part of a frameset, cURL just displays the frameset page. If I choose not to follow redirects when requesting the login page, I simply get a message saying 'object moved' - and a link to the frameset page. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
<? 

$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "COOKIE");

// INITIAL REQUEST TO SITE TO GET COOKIE

$ch = curl_init();

$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US)"
   . "AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
   . "Chrome/10.0.648.151 Safari/534.16";

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.nwolb.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);


// EXTRACTING OTHER POSS REDIRECTS / FRAMESET URLs FROM RESULTING PAGE...

// A Javascript function on the default.aspx page specifies a 
// top.window.document redirect, I store this in $newurl in case it's needed
preg_match('/top\.window\.document\.location\.href = \'(?P<url>.*)\';/', $data, $newurl);

// It's the login page I want, the Frameset page does specify a link, 
// but (what I assume is) the frame-breaking protection sends me back to
// the frameset page every time...
preg_match('/login.aspx\?(?P<referer>.*)"><\/frame>/', $data, $loginurl);

//Subsequent request, attempting to bring up the login page
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.nwolb.com/login.aspx?' . $loginurl['referer']);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Is this an experiment worth abandoning, or can it probably be achieved? Is PHP the right tool for the job? Or might it be better to try something like Watir on Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

Just because you can doesn't mean that you should.  Banking is strictly regulated and by offering an app that scrapes a banking site, you are essentially offering banking services and may find yourself regulated the same as the bank - not to mention liable for any breach that occurs through your app.

You would also be violating the TOS of Natwest and any app that scrapes their (or any other bank's) site would likely find itself sued very quickly out of existence.

That said, if you really want to scrape the site you should be looking at the "Accessibility" link at the bottom.  Not much difference between a screen reader and a screen scraper.

Comment: Hmm, you raise a good point on the fact I'd be offering a banking service by proxy, and would likely be shut down in no time at all / sued. I hadn't actually thought of that... 

I won't go through with it. I'm still interested in the solution if there is one... purely because you never know what may come up in future. The Accessibility link you refer to basically tells people that the site is compatible with browsers/OS with accessibility options and that they can use the telephone service if they're hard of hearing etc..

Comment: Whoops - you're right.  I mistook that "load accessibility page" feature to mean "load a page for screen readers" instead of what it actually is - "load the page that says 'we support screen readers'."  But the strategy is sound - if you find pages that support mobile devices or screen readers they are usually much less dependent on iframes, script, embedded media, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is certainly possible to automate this. However your service may be broken when the bank decides to update their website in future.

To find out what data is required try monitoring your login with a firefox extension like [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) or [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/).
Then replicate all the required data and headers in your script. Make sure to set the user-agent and referrer headers because they are often required.

Answer (score 0):

get_browser — Tells what the user's browser is capable of

```
<?php
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*)
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) 
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [backgroundsounds] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    [activexcontrols] =>
    [cdf] =>
    [aol] =>
    [beta] => 1
    [win16] =>
    [crawler] =>
    [stripper] =>
    [wap] =>
    [netclr] =>
)
```

refrence:php manual